# Determine the communication classes for this Markov Chain

Tags: markov-process

Say we have a Markov Chain with probability matrix

$$ P = \begin{pmatrix} 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0.66 & 0 & 0.33 & 0 \\
0 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 \\
0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0.25 & 0.25 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0.8 \end{pmatrix} $$

I'm confused, it may seem really basic but I don't want to leave it to chance in the exam.

What would be the communication classes.

I would have thought that there would be only one as all the states communicate, hence it is irreducible.

But states 4 and 5 could be a class?

Answer (score 6):

I was not familiar with the definition of communicating classes for Markov chains, but found agreement in the definitions given on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Reducibility) and on this [webpage](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~yms/M2_2.pdf) from the University of Cambridge.

Assume that $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ is a time homogenous Markov Chain. Both sources state a set of states $C$ of a Markov Chain is a communicating class if all states in $C$ communicate.  However, for two states, $i$ and $j$, to communicate, it is only necessary that there exists $n>0$ and $n^{\prime}>0$ such that

$$
P(X_n=i|X_0=j)>0
$$

and

$$
P(X_{n^{\prime}}=j|X_0=i)>0
$$

It is not necessary that $n=n^{\prime} = 1$ as stated by @Varunicarus. As you mentioned, this Markov chain is indeed irreducible and thus all states of the Markov chain form a single communicating class, which is actually the definition of irreducibility given in the Wikipedia entry.

It is often helpful for problems with small transition matrices like this to draw a directed graph of the Markov chain and see if you can find a cycle that includes all states of the Markov Chain.  If so, the chain is irreducible and all states form a single communicating class.  For larger transition matrices, more theory and\or computer programming will be necessary.

Comment: Worth a quick mention: the link to the University of Cambridge webpage is very good. It contains two very nice examples complete with solutions and graphs.

Comment: Credit where credit is due: Since it's not obvious from the pdf at Cambridge, the pdf appears to be by [Yuri Suhov](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~yms).

Answer (score 4):

**In an irreducible Markov Chain all states belong to a single communicating class.**

The given transition probability matrix corresponds to an irreducible Markov Chain. This can be easily observed by drawing a state transition diagram.

[image]

Alternatively, by computing $P^{(4)}$, we can observe that the given TPM is regular. This concludes that the given Markov Chain is irreducible. 
$$ P^{(4)} = 
\begin{matrix}
 0.1576938 & 0.2583928 & 0.08312500 & 0.2327933 & 0.2588625\cr
 0.1655115 & 0.2854474 & 0.11632500 & 0.2161569 & 0.1923158\cr
 0.1500375 & 0.1895678 & 0.09953125 & 0.2075683 & 0.3465500\cr
 0.1218750 & 0.2135125 & 0.10625000 & 0.2215688 & 0.3334688\cr
 0.1277500 & 0.0615000 & 0.07750000 & 0.1892750 & 0.5437250\cr
\end{matrix}
$$

Answer (score -3):

Communicating Classes for this matrix would be: {1}, {2}, {3}, {4,5}.

State 4 and 5 communicate with each other directly, therefore they constitute the same communicating class -- they are an equivalent class . The rest of the states do not have two way direct communication. For example you may access state 1 from 4 but not state 4 from 1, therefore states 4 and 1 are not in the same communication class.

*Disclaimer: So I just started learning this topic myself -- I feel your pain of having a poor lecturer -- and thus the above is a result of novice understanding.*