# Is this Markov chain irreducible?

Tags: self-study, markov-chain

I am trying to figure out if this Markov chain is irreducible and if it is aperiodic and why or why not.

[image]

For me it is not irreducible Markov chain because you cannot go from state 2, 5 or 6 to any of the states 1, 3, 4. I don't know if my argument is good.

Comment: Is this for some subject?

Comment: Very closely related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58042/determine-the-communication-classes-for-this-markov-chain.

Answer (score 8):

You totally got it... a drawing helps:

[image: Markov chain]

It’s not irreducible, {1, 4}, {3} and {2, 5, 6} are the communication classes, and {2, 5, 6} is an absorbing class...

Comment: There is a mistake in the drawing I guess. In the drawing from state 3 it goes to state 1  with probability 1 and in the matrix it leads from state 3 to state 2 with probability 1.

Comment: woups... I corrected this. Your argument is still correct...

Comment: Thank you for help :) If you could also help me with the following problem I would be glad.
I have to determine periodicity of the states of the chain and I think that the chain is aperiodic but I don't know how to argument it. Mabye there is some calculation that I can do to prove it? I also think that state one can have a period 2 because it can be visited only at the multiple of two moves. Is that correct reasoning? 

And the last thing. To determine stationary distribution should I first reduce the chain to states 2, 5, 6? Without such a reduction I cannot solve balanced equations.

Comment: Pepto, your question in the comment there goes far beyond clarification, to a substantive additional question. It's a bit much to ask Elvis for one-on-one responses; you should instead address such questions to the whole site - that is, you should either edit your original question to reflect what you meant to post to begin with, or post a new question (with, if necessary, a link back to this one).

Comment: sorry for that and thank you for reminding me. I have posted it now as a separate question.